# vue-flatpickr-component w/ nuxt

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

How do I get this to work with nuxt3? I've tried adding it to transpile build, I've also tried adding it as a plugin. Transpile worked closest, but the rendering was all wack.

tried adding vue-flatpikr-component to nuxt.config -> build -> transpile
tried creating a plugin with flatpickr

```js
//flatpickr.js
import flatPickr from "vue-flatpickr-component";

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  nuxtApp.vueApp.use("flatPickr", flatPickr);
});
```

```
//nuxt.config.ts
  plugins: [{src:'~/plugins/flatpicker.js', ssr: false}],
```

```js
// Datepicker.vue
<template>
  <div class="relative">
      <flat-pickr class="form-input pl-9 text-slate-500 hover:text-slate-600 font-medium focus:border-slate-300 w-60"
        :config="config" v-model="date"></flat-pickr>

      <div class="absolute inset-0 right-auto flex items-center pointer-events-none">
        <svg class="w-4 h-4 fill-current text-slate-500 ml-3" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
          <path
            d="M15 2h-2V0h-2v2H9V0H7v2H5V0H3v2H1a1 1 0 00-1 1v12a1 1 0 001 1h14a1 1 0 001-1V3a1 1 0 00-1-1zm-1 12H2V6h12v8z" />
        </svg>
      </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// import flatPickr from 'vue-flatpickr-component'

export default {
  name: 'Datepicker',
  props: ['align'],
    data (props) {
      return {
        date: null, // refer to https://github.com/ankurk91/vue-flatpickr-component
        config: {
          mode: 'range',
          static: true,
          monthSelectorType: 'static',
          dateFormat: 'M j, Y',
          defaultDate: [new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 6), new Date()],
          prevArrow: '<svg class="fill-current" width="7" height="11" viewBox="0 0 7 11"><path d="M5.4 10.8l1.4-1.4-4-4 4-4L5.4 0 0 5.4z" /></svg>',
          nextArrow: '<svg class="fill-current" width="7" height="11" viewBox="0 0 7 11"><path d="M1.4 10.8L0 9.4l4-4-4-4L1.4 0l5.4 5.4z" /></svg>',
          onReady: (selectedDates, dateStr, instance) => {
            instance.element.value = dateStr.replace('to', '-');
            const customClass = (props.align) ? props.align : '';
            instance.calendarContainer.classList.add(`flatpickr-${customClass}`);            
          },
          onChange: (selectedDates, dateStr, instance) => {
            instance.element.value = dateStr.replace('to', '-');
          },
        },                
      }
    },  
   components: {
     flatPickr
   },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, what did you tried exactly and what is not working? Which version? Got a Nuxt config file to share?

Comment: @kissu updated with code example